# Mock a third party library Class in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
    public class PersonProcessor()
    {
        private MySqlDbConn sqlConn;

        public PersonProcessor(MySqlDbConn sqlConn)
        {
            this.sqlConn = sqlConn;
        }

        public SqlResult GetAllPersons()
        {
            var query = "select * from person";
            var result = sqlConn.executeQuery(query);
            return result;
        }

        // Some other methods I want to test as well
    }
```

How would I go on about unit testing this class?
I'd like to test the `GetAllPersons()` method without actually having to create a real connection to a real database (this is especially the case when I do any write operations)

This is what I have so far: To create an instance of my `PersonProcessor` class I need to give the class a Sql connection. Unfortunately the **Sql connection object is from a third party library**, in this case from a SQL library. This means that I am unable to create a Mock object of it to generate a fake connection, which should return predefined values, because Moq only supports abstract classes and interfaces.

How do I solve this problem? Should I just create a wrapper class, which calls the exact same functions and implements an interface and then restructure the entire programm to se the wrapper classe with the interface just to unit test a simple function?

I don't believe that my idea would be the best solution and wonder what else could be done to fix this problem. Is there mayybe another way to mock entire tird party classes?

Comment: well it is best idea ... you don't wana test if `sqlConn.executeQuery` works fine but if `GetAllPersons`(and other methods) returns/does what you want

Comment: also check if `MySqlDbConn` doesn't have some interface which can be used instead ... it would save you writing a wrapper (well ...  not if `executeQuery` and others are extension methods ... (Dapper) )

Comment: Moq supports virtual methods, so minimum effort would be to make them virtual but its obviously not ideal.

Comment: Is this third party library publicly available on nuget.org?

Comment: @PeterCsala Unfortunately it is not from nuget